# Installing 6-20R receptacle in the kitchen (Ontario)

Tags: electrical, wiring, canada

Was thinking of installing one in order to take advantage of 240V countertop appliances (i.e. a heavy-duty induction cooktop)

Are there any specific Canadian electrical code requirements for installing heavy-duty receptacles in your kitchen?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Interesting question; let's see if one of our pros can answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe CEC does the same as NEC regarding you must have a recep within 2' of anywhere along the back edge of kitchen counters (following the wall). That's because kitchen appliances have 2' cords.  240V receps don't count for this, so don't convert a receptacle unless you're sure you're covered.

I don't believe CEC requires GFCI protection on 240V circuits (we add that in 2020 NEC), but *that's something you'll really, really want for countertop appliances if it's within 6' of a sink*.  On a 240V circuit, GFCI can only be done at the breaker.